# Is one of these syntaxes works faster or both equals?

Tags: jquery

I heard, that second syntax is much faster. Is it right?

```
$('div *')
```

or

```
$('div').find('*')
```

Or both take equal time?

**EDIT:**
Ok, downvoters, lets see this [TEST](http://jsperf.com/selector-specific-vs-find/2) (thanks to @AlienWebguy). Can anybody explain?

Comment: Why did edit your question to include a test that uses different selectors than the ones you asked about.  Selector performance is entirely about a specific selector against a specific body of HTML.  You've asked about a selector, not specified a body of HTML to test it against and then added a test that isn't even the same selector.  This is looking more like a worthless question with no meaningful answer because there's no required detail to the question and an example that isn't even about the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exact results may depend upon the page HTML and specific selector query, but [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-speed-with-find) says that the `$('div').find('*')` is way, way slower than `$('div *')` in the HTML case I picked.

For a question like this to be meaningful, you have to specify an exact selector and a body of HTML that you're going to run it against.

Now that you've added a test that uses some specific HTML (but a different selector), I thought I'd run your HTML from that test against the actual selectors you asked about in a test that actually tests what you asked about.  In Chrome 13, I find the `$('div *')` selector to be **9 times faster** than `$('div').find('*')` when run against the HTML in your test.  You can see the [jsperf here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-performanace).

Answer (score 1):

in Chrome 10, i don't get the same results as jfriend00.

When i try the test given by DotNET Ninja, `$('#div').find('*')` is **61% faster** than `$('#div *')`. As far as i understand jquery, it is faster because `$('#div *')` is *interpreted* into `$('#div').find('*')` so this takes longer.

But jquery selectors have been optimized by jquery developpers and you may not get the same results for each selector combination.

Comment: The question was about `$('div *')` vs. `$('div').find('*')` which is not what the jsperf you're commenting on is testing.  I get the same result as you on the OP's jsperf.  My comments are about my own jsPerfs which use the selectors that are in the actual question.

Comment: OK good, just wanted to make sure we were on the same page.  Our comments crossed in the ether and I removed my earlier comment.

Comment: @jfriend00: i understand. yet, the situation is clearer with your comment on the original post

Comment: indeed :). Yet, he accepted your answer so that probably means you eventually gave him the information he needed.